# What is the possesive of the plural of latch?

Tags: possessives

How would you refer to the levers for a group of latches?

Would that be:

1. "the latches's levers"
2. "the latches levers"
3. "the latches' levers"

Thank you!

Comment: Or just *latches'*.

Comment: @deadrat Thanks for your comment. I updated the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Is there any reason why you would not simply apply the standard rule for possessive plural?

Comment: http://www.englishgrammar.org/formation-possessive-case/ - I would prefer: the levers of the latches. With things the of-genitive is preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### "The Latches' levers"

"Latches's" is not a word, unless there is a singular "latches" that I don't know about, and "latches" is not posessive at all. Just remember that if it is plural, the apostrophe goes after the "s." (E.g. "ladies'" or "cameras'")